# Cannot see ionic app icon after install of ionic app

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, node.js, ionic-framework

I am searching from 2 months regarding app icon in ionic. but failed to set app icon.

I want to mention what i have done.

after running => ionic resources --icon

I can see the images in this folder `\resources\android\icon`.

I think there is no problem in my project

even i have tried to make scratch project and done the same but same result.

- ionic version 2.1.12
- npm version 4.0.2
- node version 5.7.0
- android version "6.0.0"
- android platform 23 or 24

Comment: Try replacing icons with the created one in drawable folder in `platform/android/res`.

Answer (score 1):

There could be some problem with the image file you are using. You can use (.png), (.psd) and (.ai) files. Try using the file in some other format instead of which you already are. Save the file within the resources directory at the root of the Cordova project. The icon image’s minimum size should be 192 by 192 px, and there should be no rounded corners. Then run this command.

Run ionic resources from CLI.
After that following folders will be created
resources > android,
resources > ios.

Add icon.png (or icon.psd or icon.ai) file in resource folder and run ionic resources command again. This will generate the splash image as well.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem. in my case new changes were not reflected to

```
/platform/android/res/ directory..
```

So I just copied content of `/res` (from project root directory) to

```
/platform/android/res.
```

Then it worked for me.

Comment: Never copy files manually to the platforms. They will be overwritten with every new build.

Comment: That is why i had to copy because everything was being overwritten with new build except the /res folder inside the platform

Comment: Okay, then have a look at my answer. Could be a solution for you as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try to update your android platform to the latest version:

```
cordova platform update android@6.1.0
```

And then run `ionic resources --icon` again.